# unix command: grep -A

Tags: unix, grep

When I try to print the first 5 lines of 'result.txt' containing the word 'CHAPTER', using the following command:

```
-grep -A 5 "CHAPTER" warandpeace.txt
```

I don't get what I am looking for.

what is wrong with my command?

Comment: What is contained in `result.txt`, do you get an error, what's the output you're seeing, etc.?  We need more information to be able to diagnose.

Comment: what about the warandpeace.txt? what about the result.txt? did you try to pipe the result ?? like  > warandpeace.txt ? What is it you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the command:

```
grep "CHAPTER" warandpeace.txt | head -n 5
```

Which attempts to find all instances of `CHAPTER`, but stops after printing the first 5 lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want the first 5 occurrences of "CHAPTER", try

`grep "CHAPTER" warandpeace.txt | head -5`

Answer (score 0):

Give `grep -m 5 "CHAPTER" warandpeace.txt` a try